# What is different between `this` and `static` in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am new with Typescript. And I want to learn about it. In Official Documentation, static described:

> Static Properties
>
> Up to this point, we’ve only talked about the instance members of the class, those that show up on the object when it’s instantiated. We can also create static members of a class, those that are visible on the class itself rather than on the instances. In this example, we use static on the origin, as it’s a general value for all grids. Each instance accesses this value through prepending the name of the class. Similarly to prepending this. in front of instance accesses, here we prepend Grid. in front of static accesses.

So the code is:

```
class Grid {
    static origin = {x: 0, y: 0};
        calculateDistanceFromOrigin(point: {x: number; y: number;}) {
            let xDist = (point.x - Grid.origin.x);
            let yDist = (point.y - Grid.origin.y);
            return Math.sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist) / this.scale;
        }
    constructor (public scale: number) { }
}

let grid1 = new Grid(1.0);  // 1x scale
let grid2 = new Grid(5.0);  // 5x scale

console.log(grid1.calculateDistanceFromOrigin({x: 10, y: 10}));
console.log(grid2.calculateDistanceFromOrigin({x: 10, y: 10}));
```

After I change `static origin = {x: 0, y: 0};` to `origin = {x: 0, y: 0};`, and

```
let xDist = (point.x - this.origin.x);
let yDist = (point.y - this.origin.y);
```

The output is same. So, what's different? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the way you are using it because you are not changing the `origin` values. Static properties or methods are mainly used outside of the class.

Also the class doesn't have to be created to use static properties/methods. So in the example below you can get the `origin` value like this.

```
class Grid {
    static origin = {x: 0, y: 0};
}

console.log(Grid.origin); // {x: 0, y: 0}
```

Where as if the `origin` value was not `static` you would have create a `new Grid()` object to get the value.

```
class Grid {
    origin = {x: 0, y: 0};
}

const grid = new Grid();
console.log(grid.origin); // {x: 0, y: 0}
```

Otherwise you get: `Error TS2339: Property 'origin' does not exist on type 'typeof Grid'.`

One thing to note is a static property will be the same across all `Grid` objects. It is class level property and not a object level property.

```
class Grid {
    static origin = {x: 0, y: 0};

    constructor() {
        console.log(Grid.origin);
    }
}

console.log(new Grid()) // {x: 0, y: 0}
console.log(new Grid()) // {x: 0, y: 0}

// Change the static value
Grid.origin = {x: 5, y: 6}

console.log(new Grid()) // {x: 5, y: 6}
console.log(new Grid()) // {x: 5, y: 6}
```

If you want the `origin` different for each object you create then don't make is static.

---

You typically don't mix class static with normal properties/methods. I've probably done in the past. In the example below we make everything static because we only want one instance of a ScoreTracker in our application.

```
class ScoreTracker {

    private static _score: number = 0;

    public static setScore(value: number): void {
        ScoreTracker._score = value;
    }

    public static getScore(): number {
        return ScoreTracker._score;
    }

    public static addPoints(value: number): void {
        ScoreTracker._score += value;
    }

    public static removePoints(value: number): void {
        ScoreTracker._score -= value;
    }

}
```

Then in our application we can do the following and we are sure our score is managed in one place.

```
ScoreTracker.setScore(10);
ScoreTracker.addPoints(1);
ScoreTracker.removePoints(2);
console.log( ScoreTracker.getScore() ); // 9
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Grid.origin` should crash if `origin` is not static. I'm saying "should" as in, "in any real OOP language". The problem is that typescript is just an intermediary that gets transpiled into js, which is not OOP, and does not know the "static" keyword.

The correct use of it is to use the `static` declaration in this case. Note that although it seems it works at runtime, your IDE should still notify you of the problem because the IDE *knows* what static means.